# Tableview ChangeListener Conflict

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have two TableView (table1 and table2) one next to the other

What I need to do is: 
When you select an item in table1 the corresponding item is selected in table2 
So far so good was easy, but I need to reproduce the same effect in table2, and it is when 
arises the `NPE` the listener applied in table1 conflict with the listener of table2. 
I tried to create an event in `focusedProperty ()` but without success :(
I made a test application to post here, as it would not fit all code follows 
download link [TableView - Teste](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__KOU0JoCQGNEU0VllBSFNKODQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like it might be a bug, but I don't have time to experiment with it properly. A workaround seems to be to update the selection in the "other" table inside a `Platform.runLater()`. You need to be careful not to create an infinite number of these calls by checking the selection really is different:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TwoTableTest extends Application {

    private ChangeListener<Number> table1SelectionListener ;
    private ChangeListener<Number> table2SelectionListener ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table1 = createTableView() ;
        TableView<Person> table2 = createTableView() ;

        table1.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        table2.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        table1SelectionListener = (obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
            int table1SelectedIndex = table1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() ;
            int table2SelectedIndex = table2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() ;
            if (table1SelectedIndex != table2SelectedIndex) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> table2.getSelectionModel().select(table1SelectedIndex));
            }
        };

        table2SelectionListener = (obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
            int table1SelectedIndex = table1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() ;
            int table2SelectedIndex = table2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() ;
            if (table1SelectedIndex != table2SelectedIndex) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> table1.getSelectionModel().select(table2SelectedIndex));
            }
        };
        table1.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(table1SelectionListener);
        table2.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(table2SelectionListener);

        HBox root = new HBox(5, table1, table2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TableView<Person> createTableView() {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().firstNameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().emailProperty());

        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")        
        );

        return table ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName;
        private final StringProperty lastName;
        private final StringProperty email ;


        Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName",
                    firstName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", lastName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "email", email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email.set(email);
        }

        public StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return email ;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return firstName.get() + " " + lastName.get();
        }

    }
}
```